# PList Chicken/Egg Scenario

Tags: iphone, url-rewriting, plist, documents

I want to read/write to cache.plist

If I want to read an existing premade plist file stored in the resources folder I can go:

```
path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathWithComponent@"cache.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *root = ...
```

But then I wish to read it from the iPhone.

Can't, the Resources folder is only readable.

So I need to use:

```
NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomain,YES
```

So how can I have my plist file preinstalled to the Document Directory location?

Thus meaning I don't have to mess around with untidy code copying the plist file over at startup. (Unless that's the only way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final product

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Cache.plist"];


NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *giveCachePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Cache.plist"];


BOOL fileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:giveCachePath];

if (fileExists) {
    NSLog(@"file Exists");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Copying the file over");
    fileExists = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:finalPath toPath:giveCachePath error:&error];
}

NSLog(@"Confirming Copy:");

BOOL filecopied = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:giveCachePath];

if (filecopied) {
    NSLog(@"Give Cache Plist File ready.");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Cache plist not working.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't really what you're after, but as far as I know the only way to get the document into the Documents folder IS to actually copy it there...but only on the first startup. I'm going something similar for a sqlite database. Code is below, it works but please note it could do with a little bit of cleaning up:

```
// Creates a writable copy of the bundled default database in the application Documents directory.
- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded {
    // First, test for existence.
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"WordsDatabase.sqlite3"];
    createdDatabaseOk = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (createdDatabaseOk) return;
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"WordsDatabase.sqlite3"];
    createdDatabaseOk = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
}
```

Just call in your AppDelegate - not too messy really?

Answer (score 1):

Easy.  Look first to see if it's in the documents directory.  If it's not, find it inside your app's Resources folder ([`[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource...]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000214-BCIBAHJF)), then copy it into the documents directory using [`[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:...]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW14).  Then use the fresh copy in the documents directory with impunity.

Comment: Primo, I think both answers are more or less what I needed to hear, kind of gives me a sanity check.

Thanks Dave deLong and alku83